# getting the index of * in a double quoted string in Bash OS X

Tags: macos, bash

In a double quoted string `"$consC"` with spaces and `*`'s that looks like this:

```
                                            * **** *****
```

How do I get the index of each of the `*`'s?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Answer (score 1):

Using brute force, ignorance, and `bash` (4.x or 3.x — but not if it is invoked as `/bin/sh` or `sh` — my head hurts after bashing it against a `sh` brick wall), you could try:

```
$ for i in $(seq 0 ${#consC}); do [ "${consC:$i:1}" = "*" ] && echo "$i [${consC:$i:1}]"; done
44 [*]
46 [*]
47 [*]
48 [*]
49 [*]
51 [*]
52 [*]
53 [*]
54 [*]
55 [*]
$
```

You could improve it with: `$(seq 0 $((${#consC}-1)) )`, which doesn't overshoot the end of the array but is even more tersely inscrutable — Perl eat your heart out!

I expect there's a better way.

(Clearly, depending on exactly how you set `consC`, you might get slightly different numbers in the output.)

Note: this was tested on Mac OS X 10.8.4, but I have a home-built `bash` 4.2 available (though I use `bash` 3.2.48 most of the time — hence the headache).  If you can't use `bash` and only has `sh`, you'll need to replace `"${consC:$i:1}"` with `"$(expr "$consC" : '^.\{'"$i"'\}\(.\)')"`:

```
$ for i in $(seq 0 ${#consC}); do [ "$(expr "$consC" : '^.\{'"$i"'\}\(.\)')" = '*' ] && echo $i; done
44
46
47
48
49
51
52
53
54
55
$
```

Or, using the `[[` operator and two fewer double quotes:

```
$ for i in $(seq 0 ${#consC}); do [[ $(expr "$consC" : '^.\{'"$i"'\}\(.\)') = '*' ]] && echo $i; done
44
46
47
48
49
51
52
53
54
55
$
```

*[...For various reasons dating back into pre-history, my shell was kludged to `/bin/sh` even after I thought I'd unkludged it to run `/bin/bash`...I've now fixed that issue! I'm running `/bin/bash` after all...and the original version without `expr` works fine with `bash` 3.2.48.]*

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  The expression `${consC:$i:1}` appears in the code; it is the substring of length 1 starting at position `$i` from the start, so effectively it is the i'th character in the string.  But the loop is controlled by the output of `$(seq 0 ${#consC})`, which is the numbers 0..56 or thereabouts.

Comment: Great; the first solution is far better than the one using `expr`.  It may be that I'm running `bash` 3.x as `sh` still — instead as `bash` — and that accounts for my headache.  Avoiding `expr` is a good general goal in life; OTOH, it is a powerful (if rather clumsy) tool.

Comment: gnu grep solution from similar question posted on http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88470/comparing-indices-of-two-strings: `grep -Fbo "*" <<<"$consC" | cut -f1 -d:` (0-based indexing; if you want 1-based, use `_"$consC"`)